# Restricting users from inserting spaces, capitol letters, first value as int in textbox using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textbox

I have a form in which I want users to only put alphabets, numbers

I want to restrict them from

1. Using the number as first value Eg. `1abc`
2. Using Capitol letters Eg. `1ABc`
3. Using Spaces Eg. `1 ab CD d5`

I only want like `abc1` OR `a1bc` OR `f25fhgfh45w`

I tried http://jsfiddle.net/m7QrG/506/ but it didn't help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RegExp` `/^\d|[A-Z\s]+/g` to match digit at beginning of string or uppercase letters or space, remove `i` flag and `$` anchor, use `input` event to also handle user pasting at `<input>` element

```js
$('.alphaonly').on('input', function() {
  $(this).val(function(i, val) {
    return val.replace(/^\d|[A-Z\s]+/g, '');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="lorem" class="alphaonly">
```

Comment: Sir, can you code it so that there will be no confusion

Comment: @Coder What confusion exists at code at Answer? See http://jsfiddle.net/m7QrG/640/

Comment: Copying the js fiddle in my file will do? or I have to add something more..

Comment: @Coder What do you mean by "more"? Have you tried code at linked jsfiddle?

Comment: In jsfiddle it's working but when I copy the codes in my file it is not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154712/discussion-between-coder-and-guest271314).

Answer (score 1):

After observing your question and your comments with @guest271314 I came up to with the solution:

```js
$(function() {     
var haveFirst = false;
$('.alphaonly').on('keypress', function (event) {
  if( $(this).val().length === 0 ) {
     haveFirst = false;
  }
var regex = new RegExp("^[a-z0-9_]+$");
var first = new RegExp("^[a-z]+$");
var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
if(!first.test(key) && haveFirst == false){
   event.preventDefault();
   return false;
}else if(regex.test(key)){
   haveFirst = true;
}
if (!regex.test(key)) {
   event.preventDefault();
   return false;
}
}); 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<input name="lorem" class="alphaonly">
```

In hoping it will work as you want!